# PIC18F2550 or PIC18F13K50?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

The PIC18F13K50 is a lot cheaper than the PIC18F2550...but it seams to be smaller, newer,  same speed, just has less RAM. Why is it cheaper? Just because it is a new one and Microchip dont like to produce the older ones, or because it has less RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIC18F13K50 is just newer, and is intended as replacement for the '2550 series. feature-wise, they are more or less on par, except for the different RAM size. I presume that the 13K50 is easier to manufacture, since it is the newer part, and comes in a smaller package (20 vs. 28 pins). But it might also be that this pricing is intentional to phase out the older parts - Microchip seems to streamline its MCU series.

Answer (score 1):

Microchip is very good about continuing production of old PICs.  You can even buy the ancient PIC16F84.  But they don't really lower the price on the old parts, so new parts tend to be cheaper and better spec'ed.

This makes Microchip a very good choice for designs with a long production lifespan.   It's a real hassle for production when your flavor-of-the-month micro gets canceled.

For a new design you will want to use the newer parts.